# Obtaining Lists from Database and Populating Array/Hashmap Using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, list, hashmap

As part of my program, I'm using relational tables which hold information such as - user role, job category etc.  Each table may have slightly differing fields - for example:

**User Role Table** has the following fields:

> - id (auto-generated)
> - role (eg Planner, Admin etc)
> - role_description (description of above role)
> - enabled (toggle this role on/off)

**Job Category Table**:

> - id (auto-generated)
> - category (eg Service, Maintenance etc)
> - category_description (description of above)
> - category_group (categories are grouped into management areas)
> - ...
> - enabled (toggle category on/off)

The lists can be changed by the end user so I need to provide an admin section to enable new roles/categories to be added.

I had thought of creating a routine where I pass the entity class of the role/category etc and have it generate an array which can be used to populate the admin section but have only been able to do this for the 1st two columns - eg id/role or id/category.

With the fields differing between each entity, is there a way that I can do this?   Or will I have to create a method in each of the entities - such as getRoleList and getCategoryList etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of experimenting, I've decided to implement this in the following way.

I've added methods to my database helper class that will read the list and populate an array.  I'll have to create a separate method for each entity but I've decided this would be necessary due to the differences between the classes.

I'm not 100% sure that this is the most efficient way of accomplishing this but it does what I need (for now).

One of the methods:

```
public static UserRole[] getUserRoleList(String order, Boolean reverseOrder) throws SQLException {
    Session session = openSession();
    List<UserRole> list;

    if (!reverseOrder) {
        // obtain list and sort by provided field in ascending order
        list = session.createCriteria(UserRole.class).addOrder(Order.asc(order)).list();
    } else {
        // sort descending
        list = session.createCriteria(UserRole.class).addOrder(Order.desc(order)).list();
    }

    // return UserRole[]
    return list.toArray((UserRole[]) Array.newInstance(UserRole.class, list.size()));
}
```

The rest of the methods will be pretty much identical (substituting the entity/class names).  The only difference would be adding another argument for some entities (enabled Boolean, so I can return only items in the list which are enabled).

**Edit:**

Since posting the above, I changed my mind and moved to a generic method to obtain lists, passing in the entity class as below:

```
    public static List getList(Class entity, String order, Boolean reverseOrder, Boolean enabled) {
    // stripped for brevity...
    list = session.createCriteria(entity)
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("enabled", true))
                            .addOrder(Order.asc(order)).list();
    // stripped more...
    return list;
    }
```

Casting when calling the method:

```
List<User> userList = DatabaseHelper.getList(User.class);
```